# auto numbering based on year and value in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

This for my dropdownlist and format for auto numbering

[image]

and if someone choose NK/W will get No.Reg :

001/NK/W/2018, 002/NK/W/2018, 003/NK/W/2018

And if someone choose NK/S will get No. Reg 001/NK/S/2018.

If years change, the auto numbering will reset to 001 again

Comment: it seems this thing relates to user interaction based on dropdown list? perhaps you need to take `javascript` into consideration. nevertheless, share with us what you have tried before downvoters come..

Comment: there is much things to do to handle it. make your question simpler then we'll help you.

Comment: Please share more information for us to work with

Comment: I dont understand the laravel code for this so I just can put that word, what you want to more information sir. @GreatDharmatma

Comment: If you can better explain the logic, i.e. what you are trying to achieve, then we can help you with the code etc.

Comment: like that, sir @GreatDharmatma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here has more to do with javascript than Laravel or PHP for instance.

Check this out

https://jsfiddle.net/j6znavy9/

```
<p>
Reg No: Auto/
<select id="mySelect">
  <option selected disabled>Select an Option</option>
  <option value="NK/W">NK/W</option>
  <option value="NK/S">NK/S</option>
  <option value="MM/A">MM/A</option>
</select>
Year: *
<select id="yearSelect">
  <option selected disabled>Select a Year</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function pad(number, size) {
    var s = String(number);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
    return s;
  }
    var year, mySelect, auto = 1;
  $('#yearSelect').on('change', function(){
    year = $(this).val();
    auto = 1;
  });
  $('#mySelect').on('change', function(){
    if( year === null || year === undefined ) {
        alert('year is not defined!');
    } else {
        alert('Reg No: ' + pad(auto, 3) + '/' + $(this).val() + '/' + year);
      auto++;
    }
  })
});
</script>
```